# formatting the colorbar ticklabels with SymLogNorm normalization in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

## TL;DR

How can you...

- Force the `LogFormatter` to use scientific notation for every label? Now it uses it for values smaller than `0` or larger than `1000`. It does not seem to expose any `set_powerlimit` method that I can find, either. Is there any way get it right or should you use a different formatter? which one?
- Get the scientific notations with the exponents as superscripts like in the first plot attached, instead of things like `-1e+02`? The `plt.xscale('symlog')` call also gets it right for an x axis, so it doesn't look like a limitation of the scale itself...

Of course, if there were a simpler way to get nicely formatted xticks and labels on a colormap with symlog scaling, that'd be great too. But honestly, looking at the colorbars that the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/users/colormapnorms.html) itself exhibits, I don't have much hope... :-/

---

## Starting from the beginning...

Matplotlib offers a few normalizations that can be used with `colorbar`. This is nicely explained in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/users/colormapnorms.html).

Among them, the logarithmic one (`mpl.colors.LogNorm`) works specially well, as it

1. places the xticks evenly distributed.
2. formats the ticklabels with a *nice looking* scientific notation**.

by itself. A minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors, ticker

data = np.arange(4).reshape(-1,1)+np.arange(4).reshape(1,-1)
data = 10**(data/2.)

plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.imshow(data, interpolation="None", cmap="gray", norm=colors.LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: imshow with LogNorm normalization]

On the other hand, the symmetric logarithmic one (`matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm`) does neither.
[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118662) defines a wrapper function for imshow that goes a long  way towards the desired results, but it does not quite get there yet.

A minimal example with an adaptation of that function:

```
def imshow_symlog(arr, vmin=None, vmax=None, logthresh=5, logstep=1,
                  linscale=1, **kwargs):
    # Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118662

    vmin = arr.min() if vmin is None else vmin
    vmax = arr.max() if vmax is None else vmax
    img=plt.imshow(arr,
                   vmin=float(vmin), vmax=float(vmax),
                   norm=colors.SymLogNorm(10**-logthresh, linscale=linscale),
                   **kwargs)

    maxlog=int(np.ceil(np.log10(vmax)))
    minlog=int(np.ceil(np.log10(-vmin)))

    #generate logarithmic ticks
    tick_locations=([-(10**x) for x in xrange(-logthresh, minlog+1, logstep)][::-1]
                    +[0.0]
                    +[(10**x) for x in xrange(-logthresh,maxlog+1, logstep)] )

    cb=plt.colorbar(ticks=tick_locations, format=ticker.LogFormatter())
    return img,cb

data2 = data - data[::-1,::-1]
plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))  
img, cb = imshow_symlog(data2, interpolation="None", cmap="gray", logthresh=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: imshow with SymLogNorm normalization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the formatter in the function to [`LogFormatterMathtext`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterMathtext):

```
cb=plt.colorbar(ticks=tick_locations, format=ticker.LogFormatterMathtext())
```

The formatters obviously lack nice (if any) documentation, but this one seems to do what you want:

[image]

Comment: Great! Sometimes matplotlib docs are a bit scarce indeed... So, I supose there's no way to get rid of the `imshow_symlog` wrapper function for now... I'll wait a bit to see if anyone comes up with a more *plug-and-play*ish solution, but otherwise this answers my question.