# adjust colours of colorbar in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Colorbar Range in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373256/set-colorbar-range-in-matplotlib)
>   [Defining the midpoint of a colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib)

When you have a colorbar in python (pyplot), it is possible to have an asymmetrical range of values

```
e.g. -4 -> 12
```

but still somehow have the white / neutral colour (usually the mid-point of the colorbar) at 0 - even though 0 is tending toward the bottom of the colorbar in this example?

Thank you.

Comment: you don't want to adjust only the limits, but to get a colormap where you can somehow specify the limits and the central point?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

It sounds like you might want to use `vmin` and `vmax` to force a range for the colorbar.  That would look like:

```
imshow(data, vmin=-12, vmax=12)
```

This will allow your data to have the range -4 to 12, and the center of colorbar will be at zero, but the colorbar will span -12 to 12.  This is useful, for example, in comparison plots between two data sets with slightly different ranges, as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373256/set-colorbar-range-in-matplotlib).

On the other hand, if you want your colorbar to have a colormap specifically derived for you data range, with a particular colors corresponding to a particular values, etc, than you'll need to make your own colormap.  It's a hassle, but not too hard.  Here's [an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html).

Comment: I need the latter of your two suggestions. Thanks!