# Adjust colorbar matplotlib using TwoSlopeNorm

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I know there are similar questions out there, but I haven't managed to solve my problem. I followed the advice in this post ([Shifted colorbar matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144529/shifted-colorbar-matplotlib/73526149#73526149)) and used TwoSlopeNorm to shift my colorbar to have negative values with blue colours and positive values with red colours (example code below). But for some reason two intervals (0-5 and 5-10) are assigned white. Then two intervals have the same red (15-20 and 20-25). How do I fix this to have different colours for each interval?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
levels = np.linspace(-5, 25, 7)
    
im0 = da6_annualtmn.plot.contourf(norm=TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=0), 
                                  cmap='bwr', extend='max', levels=levels)
```

[image]