# Matplotlib function to center color palette on zero?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I know about questions as the following:

[Defining the midpoint of a colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib)

[matplotlib bwr-colormap, always centered on zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500541/matplotlib-bwr-colormap-always-centered-on-zero)

Is there a function (e.g. distributed with matplotlib) that automatically centers the colormap on zero and does not display a symmetrical colorbar like in the second example?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144529/shifted-colorbar-matplotlib/20146989#20146989  as well as the questions you linked.  The function in matplotlib is the second example, and it's limited to discrete colormaps.  Paul Hobson has a PR to add this style of normalization to matplotlib: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3858

Comment: Oh, good news! Thanks a lot!