# The different result when I set `vmin` and `vmax` with different plot type

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, colormap, grib

#### Background

For plotting 2-d spatial distribution of some attribute, `contourf` and `pcolormesh` are both good choice as a visualization form.

Due to the actual meaning of the plotting data, I want to **set the value nearby zero are showing in white color(for example, [-0.2,0.2]); and zero value should be the midpoint**

From the question [[Defining the midpoint of a colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib?answertab=votes#tab-top]), I tried to set `vmin` and `vmax` to adjust the colormap.

#### Data import

```
import pygrib
grib='fnl_20141110_12_00.grib2';
grbs=pygrib.open(grib)
grb = grbs.select(name='Vertical velocity')[8]#Vertical velocity
data=grb.values
lat,lon = grb.latlons()
```

#### 1. Contourf plot

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=110,llcrnrlat=34,urcrnrlon=122,urcrnrlat=44,projection='mill')
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
x, y = m(lon, lat)
cs = m.contourf(x,y,data,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)

cb = m.colorbar(cs,"bottom", size="5%", pad="8%")
ax1.set_title("Original",fontsize = 15)

ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
cs = m.contourf(x,y,data,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu,vmin = -1.8,vmax =1.8)
cb = m.colorbar(cs,"bottom", size="5%", pad="8%")
ax2.set_title("symmetrical vmin & vmax",fontsize = 15)
```

[image]

#### 2. Pcolormesh plot

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=110,llcrnrlat=34,urcrnrlon=122,urcrnrlat=44,projection='mill')
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)
cb = m.colorbar(cs,"bottom", size="5%", pad="8%")
ax1.set_title("Original",fontsize = 15)

ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu,vmin = -1.8,vmax =1.8)
cb = m.colorbar(cs,"bottom", size="5%", pad="8%")
ax2.set_title("symmetrical vmin & vmax",fontsize = 15)
```

[image]

I upload the data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQSHRoSkZXT09ZM0k) as an .grib2 file. If you are interested, you can download it

#### My doubt

1. With the **contourf** plot type, setting symmetrical `vmin` and `vmax` couldn't adjust zeron to the midpoint of the colormap. That's different from **pcolormesh**.
2. The same colormap `RdBu_r` ==> different result in `contourf` and `pcolormesh`. In `pcolormesh` plot, the middle partof colorbar are shown in `white color`. But in `contourf` plot, the white color seemed to be ignored.