# Matplotlib imshow - 'speed up' colour change in certain value ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm currently working to plot some labels over the x,y axis in imshow, but over 95% of the points sit in the 0-0.2 range, whereas less than 10% sit in the 0.2-1.0 range. Using the default 'jet' colourmap, this results in almost all the plots showing up as blue, even though there is variance in 95% of the data that becomes visually unobservable.

Is there a way to tell matplotlib to, for example, quadruple the rate at which the colours change in the 0.0-0.1 range, and scale the remaining 0.2-1.0 range accordingly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Seeing at this is just a visual representation, I realised that one option I have is to instead re-scale the data in the 0.2 range down to whatever value I see fit so that the changes are more visible, then manually create the colour bar accordingly. I would still prefer to be able to have matplotlib's imshow do this natively if at all possible though.

Comment: A general tip: don't ever use the `jet` colormap. In 99.9% of cases, there is a better choice. The new standard colormap in matplotlib 2 is `viridis`. It is more pleasing to the eye, color-blind friendly and displays data in a more logical way without false implications like `jet` does. Edit: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU) says everything about why `jet` is bad.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've come across that statement here and there, without paying it too much attention. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Did you read the [Colormap Normalization arcticle](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html) on the matplotlib site?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have, but can't figure out from there how I would rescale the data *while* still showing the original values correctly on the colour bar.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but the idea of colormap normalization would be not to change your data, but the colormap instead, e.g. to a logarithmic scale.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to emphazise small values in your data in an image plot, I would never change the actual data itself. That can lead to a lot of confusion.
Instead, as I said in the comments, change the colormap.

Ways of doing so are documented in the [Matplotlib Color Normalization Tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html) as well as here on SO. Especially [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib) and the answers within are really illustrative of the possibilities one has.

I combined two concepts in the example below to show the options.

- One is to rescale the colormap such that the value that initially was at the middle (`midpoint`) of your colormap is shifted down. In this way more variation is added between `0` and the new `midpoint`, while everything above is stretched. One can think of this as two linear colormaps spliced together.
- The other is to simply use a logarithmic scaling of the colors.

This is the example code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors


def shiftedColorMap(cmap, start=0, midpoint=0.5, stop=1.0, name='shiftedcmap'):
    '''
    function taken from
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/...
        ...defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib
    Function to offset the "center" of a colormap. Useful for
    data with a negative min and positive max and you want the
    middle of the colormap's dynamic range to be at zero

    Input
    -----
      cmap : The matplotlib colormap to be altered
      start : Offset from lowest point in the colormap's range.
          Defaults to 0.0 (no lower ofset). Should be between
          0.0 and `midpoint`.
      midpoint : The new center of the colormap. Defaults to 
          0.5 (no shift). Should be between 0.0 and 1.0. In
          general, this should be  1 - vmax/(vmax + abs(vmin))
          For example if your data range from -15.0 to +5.0 and
          you want the center of the colormap at 0.0, `midpoint`
          should be set to  1 - 5/(5 + 15)) or 0.75
      stop : Offset from highets point in the colormap's range.
          Defaults to 1.0 (no upper ofset). Should be between
          `midpoint` and 1.0.
    '''
    cdict = {  'red': [],  'green': [], 'blue': [],  'alpha': []  }

    # regular index to compute the colors
    reg_index = np.linspace(start, stop, 257)

    # shifted index to match the data
    shift_index = np.hstack([
        np.linspace(0.0, midpoint, 128, endpoint=False), 
        np.linspace(midpoint, 1.0, 129, endpoint=True)
    ])

    for ri, si in zip(reg_index, shift_index):
        r, g, b, a = cmap(ri)

        cdict['red'].append((si, r, r))
        cdict['green'].append((si, g, g))
        cdict['blue'].append((si, b, b))
        cdict['alpha'].append((si, a, a))

    newcmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap(name, cdict)
    plt.register_cmap(cmap=newcmap)

    return newcmap


x = np.linspace(-3, 3, num=601)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = np.sinc( (X*np.cos(1)+Y*np.sin(1))**2 +(-X*np.sin(1)+0.2*Y*np.cos(1))**2 )**2 

orig_cmap = matplotlib.cm.viridis 
shifted_cmap = shiftedColorMap(orig_cmap, midpoint=0.05, name='shifted')


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,9))
ax = [fig.add_subplot(3,1,n+1) for n in range(3)]

# normal cmap
im0 = ax[0].imshow(Z, interpolation="none", cmap=orig_cmap)
fig.colorbar(im0, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('Default behavior (hard to see small values)', fontsize=10)

#example using the custom shiftedColorMap function
#taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib
im1 = ax[1].imshow(Z, interpolation="none", cmap=shifted_cmap)
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('Center of colormap shifted to 0.05', fontsize=10)

#example using colors.LogNorm()
#taken from http://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html
im2 = ax[2].imshow(Z, interpolation="none", norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=10e-5, vmax=Z.max()), cmap=orig_cmap)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax[2])
ax[2].set_title('Logarithmically scaled Colormap', fontsize=10)

for axis in ax:
    axis.set_yticks([])
    axis.set_xticks([])
plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

producing

[image]