# Custom limits colormap matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

These are my [attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kett.jpg) to do the following.

The colormap should start at zero and end at the maximum. The tipping point between the two colors should be at 1,0. Now most points are reddish, which isn't desired.

I tried this:

```
cbar.set_clim(0.0, 2.0)
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLbmI.png) is the colormap I want to have.

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions about this already, but I'm not sure which one to mark as duplicate:

- [Defining the midpoint of a colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib)
- [Shifted colorbar matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144529/shifted-colorbar-matplotlib)
- [Matplotlib imshow - 'speed up' colour change in certain value ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302485/matplotlib-imshow-speed-up-colour-change-in-certain-value-ranges)
- [Defining the midpoint of a colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib)