# Conditional colormap based on some threshold value for 3D surfaces using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface

I have some three dimensional dataset where each data point is of form `(x,y,z)`. I want to make a 3D plot where `z` is expressed as a function of both `x` and `y`, in the form of a 3D surface. For that, I am using the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap='viridis',edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

Now, I have a baseline point `(x0,y0,z0)`, and **I want to have the surface's colormap to be defined as a function of `z0`**. More specifically, I want a different colormap for `z<z0` and `z>z0`, for example an intensifying red colormap for `z<z0` and a green one for `z>z0`.

**How can I achieve that using `matplotlib`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my case based on this answer: [Defining the midpoint of a colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56699813/5767535). We define a colour map norm with `z0` as the centre, then we choose the colour scheme `RdYlGn` which goes from green to red, where `X, Y, Z` are `numpy.ndarrays`:

```py
minz = min(Z.flatten()) 
maxz = max(Z.flatten())
cnorm = plt.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=minz, vcenter=z0, vmax=maxz)

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap='RdYlGn',norm=cnorm,edgecolor='none')
```